# Seg Fault in c++ quicksort algorithm on array of 500,000 sorted integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I am having a problem with my quicksort algorithm in c++. I am running on 3 different input files of 500,000 integers each. The 1st and 3rd run as they should, while the 2nd causing a segfault. The 1st has 500,000 unsorted integers, the 2nd has 500,000 sorted integers, and the 3rd has 500,000 sorted integers in reverse order. I uploaded the 2nd input file here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=43088934371978831513

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int unsorted[500010];
int low = 0;
int high = 500000;
int y = 0;
int x  = 0;
int pivot = 0;
void read()
{
    int x;
    for (x = 1; x <= 500001; x++)
    {
        cin>>unsorted[x];
    }
}

void printOut()
{
    int x;
    for (x = 1; x <= 500000; x++)
    {
        //cout<<unsorted[x]<<endl;
        if (unsorted[x - 1] > unsorted[x])
        {
            cout<<"This list is not sorted!"<<endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout<<"This list is sorted!"<<endl;
}

int median(int left, int right)
{
    int middle = (right / 2);
    if(unsorted[left] > unsorted[middle] && unsorted[left] < unsorted[right])
        return left;
    else if(unsorted[middle] > unsorted[left] && unsorted[middle] < unsorted[right])
        return middle;
    else if(unsorted[right] > unsorted[middle] && unsorted[right] < unsorted[left])
        return right;

    if(unsorted[left] < unsorted[middle] && unsorted[left] > unsorted[right])
        return left;
    else if(unsorted[middle] < unsorted[left] && unsorted[middle] > unsorted[right])
        return middle;
    else if(unsorted[right] < unsorted[middle] && unsorted[right] > unsorted[left])
        return right;
    else
        return left;
}

void intSwap(int a,int b)
{
    //cout<<"intSwap::   "<<"low: "<<low<<" high: "<<high<<endl;
    int tmp;
    tmp = unsorted[a];
    unsorted[a] = unsorted[b];
    unsorted[b] = tmp;
}

int partition(int low, int high)
{
    //cout<<"partition:: "<<"low: "<<low<<" high: "<<high<<endl;
    x = 0;
    pivot = median(low,high);
    int pivotValue = unsorted[pivot];

    //intSwap(median(low,high),high);
    intSwap(pivot,high);

    int index = low;

    for (x = low; x < high; x++)
    {
        //cout<<"ONE"<<endl;

        if (unsorted[x] <= pivotValue)
        //if (unsorted[x] <= unsorted[index])
        {
            //cout<<"TWO"<<endl;
            intSwap(x, index);
            index += 1;
            //cout<<"THREE"<<endl;
        }
    }
    //cout<<"FOUR"<<endl;
    intSwap(index,high);

    //cout<<"index:: "<<index<<endl;
    return index;
}


void quicksort(int low, int high)
{
    //cout<<"quicksort:: "<<"low: "<<low<<" high: "<<high<<endl;
    int p;
    if (low < high) //else, we're at the end
    {
        p = partition(low, high);
        quicksort(low, p - 1);
        quicksort(p + 1, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    read();
    cout<<"read complete"<<endl;

    clock_t t = clock();
    quicksort(1,500000);
    t = clock() - t;
    printOut();
    cout<<"It took me "<<t<<" clicks ("<<((float)t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<" seconds)"<<endl;
    //partition();
    //cout<<unsorted[median(0,500000)]<<endl;
    //quicksort();
}
```

gdb is telling me that the program is segfaulting here:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048984 in partition (low=424752, high=500000)
at quicksort.cpp:69
69          pivot = median(low,high);
```

If anyone could give me a hand here, I would really appreciate it! Please note that the algorithm may take several minutes to run!

Comment: If you quicksort implementation runs for several minutes on an array with `500,000` integers, something is definitely wrong with it.

Comment: a) Get rid of global variables

Comment: What about asking your debugger first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that looks odd is the line:

```
int middle = (right / 2);
```

This does not always return an element between left and right.

Perhaps try instead:

```
int middle = left + ( (right-left) / 2);
```

The current code might result in a pivot value that doesn't reduce the length of the array, and therefore you end up with an infinite recursion that eventually crashes when all the stack space is used up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! That was exactly it!